# Resizing problem

Tags: transforms

Say i have a cube. I want to increase the size of one face only. I select resize tool. I drag in one direction to increase size, like in every 3d programme i know. BUT, in Blender3d it seems to increase along the Z+ AND Z- axis at the same time, NOT, just along the Z+ Axis. I have NOT selected any Mirroring, so why is this happening? No Mirroring is selected or highlighted, how do i disable this annoying feature? An how do i prevent it from automatically turning itself back on again every time i start a new object?

I have looked everywhere, but no Mirroring is selected, an no XYZ boxes are highlighted. An i cant seem to find a option to turn this feature off. It must be something so simple, but i cant seem to find a answer anywhere? Theres a similar question here already about this, but the answer does not apply, it goes on what to do to disable mirroring after you have activated it, i haven't activated anything, resizing was the only action attempted!

Comment: Hello and welcome. Are you doing this in object mode or edit mode ? if you are in edit mode are you selecting the one face that you want to move or the whole mesh?

Comment: if you decide to scale on Z it will scale on +Z and -Z, if you don't want that you can change the Transform Pivot Point to 3D Cursor for example and the 3D cursor will be the center of the scale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender scales from the *pivot point*.  You control what Blender thinks of as the pivot point by setting the pivot point in the *Transform Pivot point* menu in the header:

[image: The transform pivot point menu]

When you scale, blender scales in *both* directions along each axis that you've chosen.  The most frequently used mechanism for changing this is to set the pivot point to either *Active Element* or *3D Cursor* rather than the default bounding box center.

If you use the 3D Cursor as the pivot point, you can use the *snapping* menu (shortcut: <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd>) to move the cursor where you want it, you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>right-mouse-click, or you can adjust the cursor location in the sidebar.

Snapping menu:

[image: snapping menu]

3D Cursor position in the sidebar *view tab*:

[image: 3D cursor in view tab of the sidebar]

Comment: Oh, ok, i thought i had done something in one of the settings, an now couldn't find it? Blender is set up creating its pivot point on the bounding box instead of the actual object itself ,unless you tell it too, interesting. I dint have a clue what was going on, never faced this when using 3D Studio Max, Lightwave, Maya, Rhino, Poser or Daz3D! An had used those for decades! Strange Blender is the only one to be set up like this, when all the others arnt? I REALLY appreciate the help. This was driving me utterly nuts lol! Thank you all :)